# How to update state with the useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a default state that looks like this:

```
const [selectedFilters, setSelectedFilters] = useState({movie: 'default' , species : 'default' , planet : 'default'});
```

How do I update the movie value to something else. I tried this :

```
  const handleMovieChange  = (e) => { 
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setSelectedFilters(prevState => ({ ...prevState, movie : e.target.value}));
  }
```

However when I change values this gives me :

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/klmaa/OneDrive/Bureaublad/swcase/client/src/App.js:48
  45 | 
  46 |  const handleMovieChange  = (e) => { 
  47 |    console.log(e.target.value)
> 48 |    setSelectedFilters(prevState => ({ ...prevState, movie : e.target.value}));
     | ^  49 |  }
  50 | 
  51 |  console.log(selectedFilters);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the arrow function here. Simply access the normal object `selectedFilters` and pass the updated value for `movie` along, creating a new object, and pass this new object to `setSelectedFilters`:

```
setSelectedFilters({...selectedFilters, movie: e.target.value});
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW, Based on React documentation, Its advised to split into multiple state variables. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables.

Following should work for your scenario.

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState("default");
const [species, setSpecies] = useState("default");
const [planet, setPlanet] = useState("default");

const handleMovieChange = e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  setMovie(e.target.value);
};
```